# How to choose a set of non-orthonormal basis vectors for the absolute space of a stationary and axisymmetric space-time in General Relativity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity

In General Relativity, the space-time is described by the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$, where $\mu,\nu=0,1,2,3$ and the interval is written as $$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$$.
A 3+1 split allows to write the above interval as $$dl^2=\gamma_{ij}dx^i dx^j,$$ where $\gamma_{ij}=\left(-g_{ij}+\dfrac{g_{0i}g_{0j}}{g_{00}}\right)$ is the $\textit{absolute}$ space metric and $i,j=1,2,3$ ([The Classical Theory of Fields (Landau & Lifshitz)](http://www.elegio.it/mc2/LandauLifshitz_TheClassicalTheoryOfFields_text.pdf), Chapter 10).

I am dealing with a problem in a stationary and axisymmetric space-time ([Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)). In some references, I found that for the 3-dimensional metric tensor $\gamma_{ij}$, it is preferable to choose a set of non-orthonormal basis vectors (instead of an orthonormal set) as follows:
$$\mathbf{e_1}=\partial/\partial r,\quad \mathbf{e_2}=\partial/\partial\theta,\quad \mathbf{e_3}=\partial/\partial\phi-(g_{t\phi}/g_{tt})(\partial/\partial t)$$.

However, I couldn't understand the reason for choosing this particular set of basis vectors and this is not discussed in details in any of the references.

My question is: What is the logic behind choosing the above set of non-orthonormal basis vectors for the metric $\gamma_{ij}$? And is this a unique set of basis vectors that corresponds to $\gamma_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is only on the pure geometric side of the question.\
A time slice give you a 3-mFranifold.
Locally, a 3 manifold is an euclidean 3 ball.
By taking $r$ as the radius and by taking a level set of that radius function, you get a 2 sphere (locally). $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the standard coordinate of the euclidean 2-sphere. The term in front of the time vector coordinate is a gauge, determining how far the time slicing is from that given by a product manifold. That explains the logic.\
As for the uniqueness of the choice, the answer is in the manner of doing the choice: there are an infinite number.

Comment: That says, it depends on the problem you are trying to solve. The problem of the perturbation and stability of the Kerr spacetime (cf the work of Klainerman, Rodnianski, Szeftel,...), and in large, the problem of the perturbation and stability of a given class of manifold, is a fascinating and challenging one, putting together several domains of Mathematic.

Comment: On the other hand, I think that there are good books on the subject that can help you. Perhaps you should begin by look more closely at the differential geometry level...

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Actually I am from Theoretical Physics background. So could you please suggest some references where I could find how to choose basis vectors for a given metric (particularly the Kerr metric)? That will be very helpful.

Comment: For me, the choice of the basis is at the core of the problem. There are numerous basis type depending on the problem you want to solve. 
In general, the choice of the basis is dictated by the form of the splitting.
For the 3+1 splitting, I don't know much about, especially, in the Kerr setting.
But, I think that B. O'Neill, The Geometry of Kerr Black Holes can help you.
On the other hand, still in the 3+1 splitting, there are many work on the search for the basis by means of Hyperbolic PDE by authors as: Choquet-Bruhat, O. Reula, Sarbach, J. York...

Comment: I'm working in the double null Foliation (2+2 splitting) and most of what I know come from: Helmut Friedrich (many of his works on the characteristic IVP in GR);   Klainerman and Nicolo, the Evolution Problem in GR; R. K. Sachs, On the Characteristic Initial Value Problem in Gravitational Theory.
So, the basis choice is intimately linked to the problem you want to solve...